# What's wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

It got 2 down votes and 3 close votes.
What's wrong with it?

[Classification of all semisimple rings of a certain order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464819/classification-of-all-semisimple-rings-of-a-certain-order)

Comment: It is a bit lacking in showing effort/thoughts/whatnot. I probably wouldn't bother downvoting (or voting to close) it, because it is sufficiently non-trivial so that lack of effort is not such a big minus as it would be in the case of a more elementary question. OTOH, the poster's history of question leaves one wondering, so I also understand those who felt differently. In other words I take the users history (or lack thereof) into account when deciding on my own action.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Could you tell me how the poster's history make you wonder?

Comment: Not much to it. His earlier questions were similarly lacking. That may have simply been a case of a new user not knowing what is expected. It looks like his latest questions are a bit better. May be Zev's explanation helped?

Answer (score 12):

It originally contained the single statement

> Classify (up to ring isomorphism) all semisimple rings of order 720.

A valid reason to downvote (hover over the downvote button to see) is that

> This question does not show research effort

which the question did not. This explains the downvotes. Some people who have the power to vote to close (including me) feel that such questions also should be closed until research effort is added. That explains the votes to close.

Now that this question has been somewhat improved, such measures are not necessary, but of course people who downvoted or voted to close may not yet have seen that the question was edited, and therefore they have not removed them. I have now retracted my downvote and vote to close.

Comment: Is there a rule that a questioner should show his effort?
As you said, there is a difference between an advice and a rule.

Comment: @MakotoKato Don't need to be a rule to draw downvotes.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Why is it OK to close a question which doesn't show effort?

Comment: Let me guess. Those who down voted think his question is homework. They don't like to give away an answer to homework. They don't like being used. I think this is petty. If you don't like being used, don't answer. Everybody is being used and using others. Give and take. If you don't like it, don't use this site.

Comment: It may be that showing effort is a good thing.
However, just because someone did not do a good thing does not mean he did a bad thing.
Punishing him for not doing a good thing is absurd.

Comment: @ZevChonoles There are tons of questions which do not show research effort and get high reps. How do you explain the discrepancy?